# In completely fair scheduler in Linux, how to calculate the initial virtual run time of a process

Tags: algorithms, process-scheduling

I am trying to implement a completely fair scheduler. I want to know how to calculate the initial value of virtual run time of a process in order to insert the process into a red black tree

Comment: Hey Dasun. This isn't a good question for cs.stackexchange because this site is mainly for algorithmic and theoretical questions, and your question seems specific to Linux. I also am not entirely sure there is enough detail to understand what you are asking, but I think you could try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I suspect it would be on-topic here if it wasn't limited to Linux.

Comment: @D.W., it is a question on how a *specific* program works...

Comment: You'd have to check how the code of the exact Linux verion you have in mind does it. There is no "general formula" for anything like this.